# How to calculate price index for natural gas in India?

Tags: price-index

Ministry of commerce and industry of India doesn't provide WPI index for Natural Gas. Is there a way to calculate the same?

Comment: Was my answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

Since 2014, this is the official formula to compute the price of NG in India:

[image]

The details of this formula, including where the data is taken from can be found [here](http://ppac.org.in/WriteReadData/CMS/201501270457045609772DatasourcesforpricecalculationNov14-March-15.PDF).

To see historical data with this formula (since 2014), see the left panel [here](http://ppac.org.in/content/155_1_GasPrices.aspx). Simply click in the period you want to see. Notice these prices are set for a six-month period.

There is more information about the context of this policy and the different pricing systems regarding natural gas for India [here](http://www.ey.com/Publication/vwLUAssets/EY-natural-gas-pricing-in-India/$FILE/EY-natural-gas-pricing-in-India.pdf).